# How to use VBA function in where condition?

Tags: sql, windows, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm using the Levenshtein distance from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243036/levenshtein-distance-in-excel) in my Access Database. Using the functionin a SELECT-Statement works when the function is in the field list. e.g.:

```
SELECT field, Levenshtein(field, 'Saturday')
FROM table
```

Where `field` is a Text-Column (Access-VarChar). Now, I want to use the function in the where-clause as a condition like

```
SELECT field, Levenshtein(field, 'Saturday') as distance
FROM table
WHERE (Levenshtein(field, 'Saturday') < 5)
```

But all Access gives me is an error saying "Conflict with types". Its the same when using `distance` in the consition instead of `Levenshtein(field, 'Saturday')`.

The levenshtein-function is defined as `Public Function Levenshtein(string1 As String, string2 As String) As Long`. So what did I do wrong?

Comment: What data type is `field`? Is it a DataTime data type?

Comment: I forgot to say: `field` is Text (Access-VarChar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have some null values in your table. Could you try this query instead?

```
SELECT field, Levenshtein(field, 'Saturday') as distance
FROM table
WHERE (Levenshtein(nz(field, ""), 'Saturday') < 5)
```

(it looks like that a `where field is not null` condition in your query is not enough, the function is tried to be evaluated anyway)

Or you can define your `Levenshtein` function as `(string1 as Variant, string2 as Variant)`, and make sure you return null if string1 or string2 is null:

```
If IsNull(string1) or IsNull(string2) Then
  Levenshtein = Null
  Exit Function
End If
```

Comment: Have to wait until monday to test this.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I would have never checked for `null` values.