# Excel Approximate Text Match

Tags: string, excel, match, vlookup, approximate

I'm trying to check how many strings in column A approximately match a string in column B.

Example:

If I have the string "angry_birds_iph_app" in column B, and "angry_birds_iph_app" and "angry_birds_adrd_app" appear somewhere in column A, I would like the function to return 2.

Comment: ... You have to be more specific about what you mean by "approximately match" - Will the only difference always only be the "iph" "adrd"? Will they always have the same beginning? Etc...

Comment: No, they will not always have the same beginning. What I mean by approximate match means that >60% or so of the string matches. It could be facebook_iph_app in in column B, and facebook_web, facebook_adrd_app, and facebook_app appear in column A. In which case, the function would return 3 @JohnBustos

Comment: Maybe some thing like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243036/levenshtein-distance-in-excel

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at the Excel Fuzzy Lookup add-in.  It is free to download from Microsoft.  The tool implements the Levenshtein edit distance algorithm to return a similarity score between rows.  Among other customizable features, the tool also allows you to set a threshold for how well the values must match in order to return the approximate result.

Rather than returning the count like you mentioned, the tool will return a table with the most similar match in column A relative to each entry in column B.  From there you could simply use a filter and perform a count on the resulting column.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the `Excel Fuzzy lookup` add-in, there is another add-in *(also a free download)* that provides a couple functions that may be helpful. One is `pwrVLOOKUP` and provides a fuzzy vlookup capability. The other is `pwrSIMILARITY` and would give you a similarity score (between 0 and 1) from which you can base your matching within your worksheet. The `PowerUps` add-in for Excel works in Excel 2003 thru 2013.

An example is posted on the page here: 
[Example Demo](http://officepowerups.com/2013/10/23/fuzzy-vlookup-in-excel/.)