# EXCEL Text Matching

Tags: excel, text, match

For Matching text and finding similarity between them, I came across two methods that one can use in Excel - Fuzzy Lookup and pwrSimilarity. Has anyone used them before. If so, can someone tell me what matching procedure (Jaccard, cosine etc.) is used for these. If I want to find similarity between two strings such as string 1 - " I am good today" and String 2 - " I am very good today" then I get different scores. For Fuzzy logic it is 0.96 and for pwrSimilarity it is 0.66.

Comment: rlb.usa you are right pwrSimilarity is a proprietary add-in but its free for download for limited time. I had checked with the  support there but didn;t get any response. So was wondering if anybody had used it. Thanks for the sources for excel fuzzy lookup.

Answer (score 0):

> The magic behind the Fuzzy Lookup Add-in comes from the Jaccard Index of Similarity. [[source]](http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/text-match-and-fuzzy-lookup/)
>
> the Excel Fuzzy Lookup ... implements the Levenshtein edit distance algorithm [[source]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14821345/excel-approximate-text-match)

There seems to be some dispute on which algorithm Fuzzy Lookup actually uses.

The `pwrSimilarity` algorithm is not mentioned at all anywhere, which would lead me to suspect that it is a custom, proprietary algorithm.