# comparing two address columns

Tags: excel, compare

I have addresses in U and V. I want to see if they are somewhat similar and if they are say "Update" If not say "Omit".

For example `246 N High street` in U and `246 North High St` in V would return a value of `Update`. 
`246 N High Street` in U and `458 Auburn Drive` in V would return a value of `Omit`.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is a difficult problem in general. You'll need to use some sort of fuzzy matching. Check out the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14821345/excel-approximate-text-match) for how to go about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of algorithms for doing fuzzy matching. One of the easier ones to implement in excel is N-Gram.

To perform an n-gram match, we have to break each address up into a list of sets of smaller character lengths. A 2-gram list of your address `246 N High street` would look like `24,46,6 , N,N , H,Hi,ig,gh,h , s,st,tr,re,ee,et`. We could do the same with a 3-gram: `246,46 ,6 N, N ,N H, Hi,Hig,igh,gh ,h s, st,str,tre,ree,eet`

We do this with both addresses, then we can check each item in the first address's list to see if it appears in the second address's list; count the matches and divide that by the number of items in the first list. That will give you a percentage of how close they are.

You could get fancy with cell formulas `mid()` and `countif()` to do this with sheet formulas, but I think it's easier to just write it out in VBA and make it a UDF.

```
Function NGramCompare(string1 As String, string2 As String, intGram As Integer) As Double
    'Take in two strings and the N-gram
    Dim intChar As Integer, intGramMatch As Integer
    Dim ngramList1 As String, ngramList2 As String, nGram As Variant
    Dim nGramArr1 As Variant

    'split the first string into a list of ngrams        
    For intChar = 1 To Len(string1) - (intGram-1)
        If ngramList1 <> "" Then ngramList1 = ngramList1 & ","
        ngramList1 = ngramList1 & Mid(string1, intChar, intGram)
    Next intChar

    'split the secong string into a list of ngrams        
    For intChar = 1 To Len(string2) - (intGram-1)
        If ngramList2 <> "" Then ngramList2 = ngramList2 & ","
        ngramList2 = ngramList2 & Mid(string2, intChar, intGram)
    Next intChar

    'Split the ngramlist1 into an array through which we can iterate
    nGramArr1 = Split(ngramList1, ",")

    'Iterate through array and compare values to ngramlist2
    For Each nGram In nGramArr1
        If InStr(1, ngramList2, nGram) Then
            'we found a match, add to the counter
            intGramMatch = intGramMatch + 1
        End If
    Next nGram

    'output the percentage of grams matching.
    NGramCompare = intGramMatch / (UBound(nGramArr1) + 1)
End Function
```

If you've never used a UDF:

1. Go to visual basic editor (VBE) with Alt+F11
2. In the VBA Project window, find your workbook and right click on the name
3. Choose: Insert>>Module
4. Double click the new module in the list to bring up it's code window
5. Paste this function in and save your workbook

Then, assuming address1 is in `A1` and address2 is in `B1` you can put, in `C1`:

```
=NGramCompare(A1, B1, 2)
```

Which, for your first address, will spit out 56%. Which seems like a reasonably good match. If you find you are getting too many positive hits, you can change your 2-gram to be a 3-gram by changing that last parameter.

To take it a step further so it will say "Update" or "Omit" you could do:

```
=If(NGramCompare(A1, B1, 2)>.30, "Update", "Omit")
```

I just set that so that it will consider a match anything above 30%, but you can adjust as necessary. No matter where you set it, you will probably end up with a percentage of compares that are false positives or false negatives, but that's the way fuzzy matching goes.

Comment: wow this is amazing, i just put it and and it worked that quickly! Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Some of the naive approaches can be to compare the first few characters

```
=LEFT(A1,5)=LEFT(B1,5)
```

or to replace parts until they match

```
=(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A2)," street"," ST")," north "," N ")
 =SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(B2)," street"," ST")," north "," N "))
```

both will probably turn into a big ugly formula after adjusting for most cases

Comment: That =Left is going to work great, i can look at the first few digits to see if they match. Thanks so much

Comment: then to get everything before the first space `= LEFT( A1, FIND( " ", A1 ) - 1 )`