# Compare Addresses in Excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to compare two columns of addresses in excel. In column A I have a long list of addresses, and in column B I have a shorter list of addresses that are all in column A. I want to be able to say which addresses in column A do not have a match in column B.

The only thing is that some of the addresses have slight differences in the list. Say, one list was a street with East, while the other just has an E. Or one list has Rd while the other has Road. Is there a way to still compare these lists?

I tried doing a conditional formatting with highlighting differences that highlight unique boxes, but with the slight variation in addresses, it doesn't give the output wanted.

Comment: probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14821345/excel-approximate-text-match or https://superuser.com/questions/437387/comparing-similar-text-strings-in-excel but i'm out of votes for today

Comment: MS has a fuzzy match add-in for Excel.  It may do the trick for you.