# Comparing two Columns in Excel and highlighting the similar ones

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro or find and add-in for Excel that would do something like this. 
I am working with two spreadsheets and both contain a list of DvD names. I need to search between the two lists and see if any of the DvD names match, doesnt have to match 100% but be similar. Some of the names can be a little different such as "JET LI'S FEARLESS/UNLEASHED" and "JET LI'S FEARLESS DIRECTOR'S CUT" are items on the first list and "Jet Li's Fearless" is the item on the other list. I want the macro to  Is there a way to write a macro that wont be case sensitive and would go through list 2 and find all items that are similar in list 1 and highlight them. I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243036/levenshtein-distance-in-excel) post and I don't really know how to implement it and have it highlight the ones that are similar.
I would be very thankful if someone could point me in the right direction. I hope I have explain myself well enough.

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered Conditional Formatting?  This feature supports assigning a formula to determine if the cells should be highlighted.  There are a number of approaches you can take to determine if two values match.

Comment: I know about conditional formation, but the problem is how do I figure out if the values match. And these values can be very different sometimes. Like missing "The" or having "(DvD)" in the title. So if im searching for "Hulk" then I want "The Hulk" "HULK (DVD)" and "HULK 1" to be highlited. Is there a way to see if it at least contains the value and have it highlight. I dont want to do one at a time because then I can just use ctrl+f and do it all manually. Im working with bigger lists here so I would like something that does it automatically.