# Within VLOOKUP, is there a way to get around having odd characters within your text string?

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I'm trying to compare columns of text where the text columns look something like:

> 1. C276 .016" x 1.18" (#) (279.4 lbs each)
> 2. C22 .016" x 1.125" (#)

Comparing the above to a list that looks like:

> 1. C276 .016" x 1.18" (#) (279.4 lbs each)
> 2. 302SS .055, 1/2" OD

I am not looking for exact matches, rather trying to find strings that are as similar as possible. VLOOKUP hates non-compact text strings and my data has quite a lot of those as well as a whole host of characters. What is a way that I can get around this?

Comment: `I am not looking for exact matches, rather trying to find strings that are as similar as possible.` - look into [Levenstein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). Here is [VBA implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243036/levenshtein-distance-in-excel).

Comment: is there a more efficient way to do this besides using Levenstein distance?

Comment: It depends on how your values are different, whether there is any pattern? But in general I don't think you can do it in easier way

Comment: I ended up going through with this. I set up a matrix of sorts. X-Axis my dependents, and Y my independents: `=IFERROR(IF(Levenshtein3($BK$1,C10) > 55, "MATCH", 0), 0)` and checked each value in the X row against a Y. I'm going to be changing the Y values and hopefully catch the strings that match. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It depends how pervasive the "odd characters" are.  You might be able to use wildcard characters * ? to approach an acceptable match.  Generally there is not an easy way to process "dirty" data through the `VLOOKUP` formula.  Your best solution is to clean up the data.

If that is not possible, then you may have to give up on `VLOOKUP` formula and use vba code instead.  You would have to write code that could parse the string and identify smaller string(s) with which to make a unique match.  It can be done, but it takes a lot of work and refinement.

Comment: I used the Levenshtein distance implemented through VBA. Works like a charm.