# How do I compare between 2 rows text but only similar not exact on Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, excel-2010

I have 2 rows that contain data like this :

**Row A**

1. El Cafe Latte
2. Carrick Hill Restaurant
3. Great Birmingham Hotel

**Row B**

1. La Tombola
2. Adelaide Cafe
3. El Café Latte
4. Hilton Hotel
5. Carrick Hills Restaurant
6. NSW Hotel and Restaurant
7. Birmingham Hotel

I want to compare between Row A-1 with Row B-1 until Row B-7 and after that I will compare Row A-2 with Row B-1 until Row B-7.

I tried with **EXACT** function, but it doesn't help because the data is not exact.
I want the formula can show me where the data have similar value.

As example :
When formula compare Row A-1 (El Cafe Latte), the formula will show Row B-3 have probability similar value.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) could help you. But I dont think excel supports it. You really need it, you have to implement it yourself.

Comment: it's a good point, btw, here is excel-vba implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243036/levenshtein-distance-in-excel

Comment: I am new into Excel. Are those codes can be input into command line or something?