# Find String value in cell that has minor modifications to the end

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I wrote this code which is part of a `Select Case` statement. It searches for a term variable (`find_Element`) and then pastes it to another `worksheet` and another `cell`.

```
Case 1
        find_Element = "Finished goods, net"

                For k = 3 To last_WS
                    With Sheets(k).Range("1:200")
                    sh_Name = Worksheets(k).Name
                    'sh_Name = Replace(sh_Name, "_", " ")
                    Set pointer_to_Element = .Find(find_Element, _
                        .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, _
                        xlNext, False)
                    pointer_Int_Row = CInt(pointer_to_Element.Row)

                    Worksheets(k).Cells(pointer_Int_Row, lock_Array(k)).Copy
                    Worksheets("EXTRACTIONS").Range("B12").Offset(, q).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    Worksheets("EXTRACTIONS").Range("B11").Offset(, q).Value = sh_Name
                    q = q + 1
                End With
            Next k

q = 1
```

However many elements like this one have **micro-variations in naming that render my code useless.**

For example sometimes the `worksheet` instead of having `Finished goods, net` in the `cell` we are looking for it has `Finished goods` or `Finished goods,`....

How can i adjust my code to enable him to find the element and not be derailed by such micromodifications in the reports i am receiving?

Comment: look into [Levenshtein Distance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243036/levenshtein-distance-in-excel)

Comment: OMG what is that...i'll check it

Comment: Isn't there something that will just check if the first two words are existent instead of searching an exact match? This Levenshtein Distance looks very tough....

Comment: You could change `xlWhole` to `xlPart` and search for "finished goods", case insensitively. It depends how consistent the users are.

Comment: that might do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `xlWhole` to `xlPart` and search for "finished goods", case insensitively.

Comment: It works sorry for the late response i was out of office