# Match items in list against themselves for semi-uniqueness

Tags: excel, match

I'm really just looking for some kind of tool that will check for close approximations of duplicates in a column of data.  For instance, say I have a column of data with addresses as such:

- 113 James Way
- 3448 Harlon Circle
- 5888 Murray Rd
- 3448 Harlon Cr.

In this case entry 2 and 4 would be very close to unique and I would like some kind of tool, either in excel or standalone, that would notify me if rows are being duplicated or approximately duplicated.  I have no idea how to even search for something like this.  I tried searches for fuzzy match tools and the like but nothing is quite what I need.  Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to approach

One simple method is to write a [Levenshtein function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243036/levenshtein-distance-in-excel) to compare these addressed with each other and highlight low values

Assume you have the data setup as follows

[image]

**Raw example**

```
Sub FindClosestMatch()
Range("B3").Select
Dim mystrings()
 Range("B3").Select
 Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
 mystrings = Selection.Value

i = 0
Dim string1 As String, string2 As String
 Range("C3").Select
For i = LBound(mystrings) To UBound(mystrings)
    string1 = mystrings(i, 1)
    For j = 1 To 4
    string2 = mystrings(j, 1)
    ActiveCell.Value = Levenshtein(string1, string2)
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Next
    Range("c3").Offset(i, 0).Select

Next
End Sub
```

**How to read values**

For e.g  `113 James Way 0 15 13 12`  means the string has a score of

- 0 (exact match) with itself
- 15 with 3448 Harlon Circle
- 13 With 5888 Murray Rd
- 12 with 3448 Harlon Cr.

etc

The Macro just compares every address with other address and finds the Levenshtein distance

The lower the number the closest match they are and clearly 0 is exact match when it compares to itself

This macro assumes you have copied the [Levenshtein function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243036/levenshtein-distance-in-excel) into your VBA Module

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how accurate you need it to be and what kind of close matches you want it to catch.  If you want to catch typos it'd be a lot harder.  But if you're mainly looking to catch St vs Street you could do a vlookup on the left(address, #) or something.  Might have to toy with the # to get a good response.  # needs to be higher then the number of digits in the street numbers (4/5?) but small enough to catch things like 1 dry ct.  I'd guess 7-8.

Basically your addresses are in column A (assuming starting in A2 with headers).  Column B says = left(a2,8)
A2 is obviously unique cause it's first.
Start in C3 with =vlookup(left(a3,8),$B$2:B2,1,0)

It'll print an error for all the unique entries and an address for the dupilcates.  To make it cleaner you can add an if(iserror()) with
=if(iserror(vlookup(left(a3,8),$B$2:B2,1,0), "", vlookup(left(a3,8),$B$2:B2,1,0))