# Merging data with text identifiers

Tags: categorical-data, dataset

I am trying to merge a bunch of datasets at the company level. The problem is my datasets only identify company name with a text string (i.e. "Ham and Cheese LLP") and further sometimes misspell or spell in alternative ways the names (i.e. "Ham and Cheese", "Ham, and Cheese", "Ham Cheese").

Is there a way to assign unique identifiers to such data using some sort of propensity matching algorithm, preferable in Excel, STATA, or MATLAB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Excel you could use the levenshtein distance function, as in the following link

[Levenshtein Distance in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243036/levenshtein-distance-in-excel&ved=0CB8QFjAA&usg=AFQjCNElzSYO4pVLI2aWi7XJBuT3ltrD5A)