# Compare strings in 2 columns and match 80%

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro which compares the first 20 characters of strings in two columns, when the customer type is "O" and gives the results. But I need to compare these two columns and if 80% of the strings match, i need to get the result as "ok" else "check". Can someone help me with correcting my code. Thanks

```
Sub Macro1()
'
'Match Organization names only the first 20 characters
'    
'
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim LR As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim str As String, str1 As String

    Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ORD_CS")
    LR = sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    With sht
        For i = 8 To LR
            If CStr(.Range("Q" & i).Value) = "O" Then
                str = Left(.Range("S" & i).Value, 20)
                str1 = Left(.Range("U" & i).Value, 20)
                If str = str1 Then
                    Range("V" & i).Value = "ok"
                Else
                    Range("V" & i).Value = "check"
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you explain what 80% of the string is? 80% of the 20 characters?16 of the 20?

Comment: check into the fuzzy lookup add on by Microsoft.

Comment: @Davesexcel - i do not want to restrict the number of characters. whatever be the length of the string if 80% of it matches, then i must have it as ok else check

Comment: I would think this strategy would work: **1)** Count the characters in column S cell . **2)** Loop through each character in column U cell and check if it's find in column S cell. **3)** If it's found throw it into a counter that is then divided by total characters in column S. **4)** Once that number is >80% trigger then OK. If it's not >80% ever mark as "Check".

Comment: Is it 80% of the right of the string or left? is it in sequence?

Comment: @Davesexcel - Left of the string. The string is Names of organization -  example: Clear Outdoor Company London

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe use len() and multiply by .8

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim LstRw As Long, Rng As Range, sh As Worksheet, c As Range

    Set sh = Sheets("ORD_CS")

    With sh

        LstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "S").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = .Range("S2:S" & LstRw)

        For Each c In Rng.Cells

            If InStr(1, c.Offset(, 2), Left(c, Len(c) * 0.8)) Then

                c.Offset(, 3) = "Yep"
            Else: c.Offset(, 3) = "Nope"

            End If

        Next c

    End With
End Sub
```

---

### Compare column s or t whichever string is smaller.

You can count the string characters to find out which one is smaller.

```
    Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim LstRw As Long, Rng As Range, sh As Worksheet, c As Range

    Set sh = Sheets("ORD_CS")

    With sh

        LstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "S").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = .Range("S2:S" & LstRw)

        For Each c In Rng.Cells
            x = IIf(Len(c) < Len(c.Offset(, 1)), 0, 1)
            If InStr(1, .Cells(c.Row, "U"), Left(c.Offset(, x), Len(c.Offset(, x)) * 0.8)) Then

                .Cells(c.Row, "V") = "Yep"
            Else: .Cells(c.Row, "V") = "Nope"

            End If

        Next c

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @ Davesexcel - This works awesome. But i have a catch here. The length of string in Column S is static. What if i want to compare the length of both columns S & T and whichever string length is minimum, that has to be considered for comparison and 80% match will be ok else check.

Comment: Count whether s or t is a smaller string.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep track of the number of hits and divide that by the total rows you are looking at:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
'Match Organization names only the first 20 characters
'    
'
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim LR As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim str As String, str1 As String
    Dim totalRows as Long, Dim matchRows as Long


    Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ORD_CS")
    LR = sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    totalRows = LR-8

    With sht
        For i = 8 To LR
            If CStr(.Range("Q" & i).Value) = "O" Then
                str = Left(.Range("S" & i).Value, 20)
                str1 = Left(.Range("U" & i).Value, 20)
                If str = str1 Then
                    Range("V" & i).Value = "ok"
                    matchRows = matchRows + 1
                Else
                    Range("V" & i).Value = "check"
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    'heres ther percentage of hits:
    if matchRows/totalRows > .8 Then
        msgbox "OK"
    else
        msgbox "Check"
    End if
End Sub
```

If it's not 80% of the total matching rows you are looking for, but rather comparing to strings to get a number of how aproximately matched they are, you could implement the Levenshtein distance function and do your compare using that. [See here for a VBA function that will do that which should be easy to implement in your code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243036/levenshtein-distance-in-vba)

Comment: I think the code was an example for the left 20 characters but OP want to look at the whole string in both cells and if the relationship in those two strings(Each row) is an 80% match then return `ok` for that row if not then `check`

Comment: I was thinking that too, but it wasn't clear so I figured I'd go with the more literal of the two. I'll delete if it's clarified.

Comment: Yeas, I want to look at the whole string in both cells and if the relationship in those two strings(Each row) is an 80% match then return ok for that row if not then check