# VBA Possible Duplicate Checker

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates

I have a list of suppliers and I want to check them to see if there are any possible duplicates.

Let's take some example supplier names:

```
1. The Supplier GmbH
2. Trading Company LLC & Co. KG
3. DHL Express
4. DHL-Express Inc.
5. Supplier GmbH
6. Trading S.a.r.l.
```

I created two regex functions:
`StripNonAlpha` that removes all non alpha characters and two letter words and replaces "-" with a space and `WordMatch` that takes two arguments and returns `True` if this specific word exists in the company name (I want to check for whole words, not partial, this is why I'm not using `InStr`).

Taking the vendor names from above, I want to have for example supplier 1 and 5, 3 and 4 marked as possible duplicates but not 2 and 6.

I have around 100K suppliers to check, but the code is running very slow. Any clues how to optimize it?

```
Function StripNonAlpha(TextToReplace As String) As String

Dim ObjRegex As Object
Set ObjRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

With ObjRegex
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "[^a-zA-Z\s]+"
    StripNonAlpha = .Replace(Replace(TextToReplace, "-", Chr(32)), vbNullString)
    .Pattern = "\b.{2}\b"
    StripNonAlpha = .Replace(StripNonAlpha, vbNullString)
End With

End Function

Function WordMatch(Source As String, MatchExprValue As String) As Boolean

    Dim RE As Object
    Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    RE.IgnoreCase = True
    RE.Pattern = "\b" & MatchExprValue & "\b"
    WordMatch = RE.test(Source)

End Function

Sub possible_duplicatev2()

Dim arr1() As String
Dim exclude(1 To 6) As String
Dim arr2() As String
Dim companyname As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim k As Long
Dim l As Long
Dim FoundCount As Long
Dim DuplicateCount As Long
Dim rc As Long
Dim scompanyname As String
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long

exclude(1) = "sarl"
exclude(2) = "gmbh"
exclude(3) = "llc"
exclude(4) = "inc"
exclude(5) = "the"
exclude(6) = "sas"

rc = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For x = rc To 2 Step -1
    If LCase(Range("B" & x).Text) Like "*zzz*" Or LCase(Range("B" & x).Text) Like "*xxx*" Or LCase(Range("B" & x).Text) Like "*yyy*" Then
        Range("B" & x).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next x


rc = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1
ReDim arr1(1 To rc, 1 To 2)

    For Each companyname In Range("B2", Range("B1").End(xlDown))
        scompanyname = StripNonAlpha(LCase(companyname))
        arr1(companyname.Row - 1, 1) = scompanyname
    Next companyname


    For i = 1 To UBound(arr1, 1)

        For j = 1 To UBound(exclude)
            If WordMatch(arr1(i, 1), exclude(j)) = True Then
                Replace arr1(i, 1), exclude(j), ""
            End If
        Next j

        arr2 = Split(arr1(i, 1), " ")
            For k = 1 To UBound(arr1, 1)
                For l = 0 To UBound(arr2)
                    If k = i Then
                        GoTo nextk
                    ElseIf WordMatch(arr1(k, 1), arr2(l)) = True Then
                        FoundCount = FoundCount + 1
                    End If
                Next l
                If UBound(arr2) = 1 And FoundCount = 1 Then
                    arr1(k, 2) = "Yes"
                    DuplicateCount = DuplicateCount + 1
                ElseIf UBound(arr2) > 0 And FoundCount > 1 Then
                    arr1(k, 2) = "Yes"
                    DuplicateCount = DuplicateCount + 1
                Else
                    arr1(k, 2) = "No"
                End If
                FoundCount = 0
            nextk:
            Next k
            If DuplicateCount > 0 Then
                arr1(i, 2) = "Yes"
            Else
                arr1(i, 2) = "No"
            End If
            DuplicateCount = 0
    Next i

For y = 1 To UBound(arr1, 1)
    Range("D" & y + 1) = arr1(y, 2)
Next y

End Sub
```

Comment: Loop through your range to clean up the company names first. As your last question does. Use something like: MyArray() = Split(Activesheet.cells(row, column), ) to get it in Array. Then loop from LBound(MyArray) to Ubound(MyArray) and check the LEN of value...use the values three or longer in a string to replace cell value.

Comment: You might be able use the [Levenshtein Distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243036/levenshtein-distance-in-vba) to assess for similarity.  It easily differentiates using your data above (but might not for a longer list).

Comment: @JvdV Good point, will do the regex cleanup function first and pass the results to a new column. I don't quite understand the second tip.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I looked this up, but it seems that it will be even longer in terms of execution.

Comment: Are you working with VBA arrays, or only with range objects. Arrays should afford an order of magnitude increase in speed.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld So would it be better to pass the whole thing into a 2d array and work on this (the 2nd dimension being duplicate yes/no)?

Comment: I may be wrong, but your question suggests a lack of familiarity with the concept.  I recommend you read about [VBA Arrays and Worksheet Ranges](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx) at (the late) Chip Pearson's excellent website.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Could you please check if this is what you had in mind?

Comment: No.  You would only read once from the worksheet, and write the results back once to the worksheet.  ie. **1** Read data into array (`myArr = dataRange`) **2** Test each *row* in the array **3** Collect results (into dictionary, collection or array). **4** write the results back to the worksheet (`myDestRange = myResultsArray`).  That should be much faster since you only access the worksheet twice.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld isn't this what I'm doing? The first loop deletes unwanted vendors and runs for couple of seconds, then the second loop reads the vendors into the arr1, which also takes a very short time. Then all the tests are done on arr1 and the last loop writes the results to the worksheet. The tests are the thing that takes most of the time (1000 rows took around 20 mins).

Comment: The following two statements seem to loop through your range and not a VBA array:  `If LCase(Range("B" & x).Text) Like "*zzz*" Or LCase …` **and also** `For Each companyname In Range("B2", …` and when you write the array back you do it line by line instead of all at once.