# String vs column - percent match

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Trying to figure out a way to calculate the minimum percentage match when comparing a string to a column.

Example:

```
Column A        Column B
Key             Keylime
Key Chain       Status
                Serious
                Extreme
                Key
```

Where

```
Column A        Column B     Column C                 Column D
Key             Temp         100%                     Key
Key Chain       Status       66.7%                    Key Ch
Ten             Key Ch       100%                     Tenure
                Extreme       
                Key
                Tenure
```

To expand on this:

- Column A is the column with strings to individually match
- Column B is the reference column
- Column C provides the highest percent match the column A string has with any string in column B.
- Column D provides the word from column B associated with the highest percent match

To expand on Column C - when looking at `Key Chain` - the highest match to any word it has in column B is for `Key Ch` where 6 out of the 9 characters (including space) of `Key Chain` match to give a percentage match of (6/9) = 66.7%

- That being said, this isn't a deal breaker but it is something that sticks out. The logic above fails when there's no way to penalize for matches where you see an example like `Ten` occur. Where `Ten` has 3 out of 3 characters that match against `Tenure` giving it an inflated 100% match that I still can't think of a way to correct against.

Comment: This may be of interest [Levenshtein_distance on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).  There are examples on SO for VBA

Comment: do you need Levenshtein distance or just left-of-string comparisons?

Comment: @iamanigeeit left of string comparisons!

Comment: also, should Ten / Tenure give you 50% or 100%?

Comment: @iamanigeeit given the logic in the post above, it would be 100% but I did add the last bullet point in the post note to say - that yes, the correct answer would be 50%, I'm just not sure how to take that correction into account when approaching this

Comment: If you are willing to add some `vba` (or an addon), check out Levenshtein (as per @chrisneilsen's comment). Also here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243036/levenshtein-distance-in-vba)

Comment: @S31 just divide by the length of the longer string, as i did in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (i haven't tested it, currently on Linux). Call `getStrMatch` for each string.

```
Type StrMatch
    Percent As Double
    Word As String
End Type

Function getStrMatch(s As String, RefRange As Range) As StrMatch
    Dim i As Long, ref_str As String
    Dim BestMatch As StrMatch: BestMatch.Percent = -1
    Dim match_pc As Double
    With RefRange
        For i = 1 to .Cells.Count
            ref_str = .Cells(i).Value2
            match_pc = getMatchPc(s, ref_str)
            If match_pc > BestMatch.Percent Then
                BestMatch.Percent = match_pc
                BestMatch.Word = ref_str
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    getStrMatch = BestMatch
End Function

Function getMatchPc(s As String, ref_str As String) As Double
    Dim s_len As Long: s_len = Len(s)
    Dim ref_len As Long: ref_len = Len(ref_str) 
    Dim longer_len as Long
    If s_len > ref_len Then longer_len = s_len Else longer_len = ref_len
    Dim m As Long: m = 1
    While m <= longer_len
        If Mid(s, m, 1) <> Mid(ref_str, m, 1) Then Exit While
        m = m + 1
    Wend
    getMatchPc = (m - 1.0) / longer_len
End Function
```

Note that you have to put this in a module or else declare `Private Type` and `Private Function`.

Also, if you're matching a lot of strings you probably should create a trie instead, as this is only doing naive string compares and each getStrMatch costs O(mn) where m is the size of the `RefRange` and n is the average `ref_str` length.