# how to find similar strings in two different array or columns in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

i have two columns one for Employee's names and i have another columns it is also Employee's names but with some added text , it is like this :

```
    A                              B                       C
Emplyee's Name                    Emplyee'Name           Emp.Code
---------------                   ------------
 Rima  Khaled                      Manal Gorge Fadel       20
 Manal Fadel                       Hib Omar                30 
 Hiba  Jamal                       Rima Osamah Kahled      40
```

suppose i have a range named (EmpList) For B and C
how can i use a vlookup or VBA Macro to get an Emp.Code For each Similar name in Column A

Comment: The names don't match from column A and B right?

Comment: can you explain better the expected result?

Comment: The similarity of two strings can be measured by the Levenshtein Distance. You'll find some VBA-examples here on Stack Overflow, e. g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4243652/10908769).