# How do i set up Levenshtein distance

Tags: excel, vba, levenshtein-distance

I've looked around various forums for comparing two strings and looking for similarity and it appears the best option is to use "Levenshtein Distance" - I've seen other peoples vba code etc but how to I set this up to compare my data in EXCEL?

seen an example here > [Levenshtein Distance in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243036/levenshtein-distance-in-vba)

but how do I set up or even begin to use this to compare my data below? the actual data has a lot more detail and some strings up to 100 characters long.

[image]

any help would be much appreciated,  I believe this is a function in VBA rather than a sub, so don't even know where to start or if levenshtein distance is the answer.

thanks

Comment: Assuming you have copied the linked code into a module of your workbook, you simply put a formula like `=Levenshtein(A2, B2)` to cell C2 and copy it down.

Comment: @FunThomas  thank you Sir, didn't realise it was that simple. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

input formula '=Levenshtein(A2, B2)'
A2 & B2 being the cells to check