# How can I get this LAMBDA function to accept an array as input?

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, levenshtein-distance, excel-lambda

I'm using this [Lambda function](https://www.flexyourdata.com/blog/calculate-the-levenshtein-distance-in-excel/) to calculate the Levenshtein distance between two strings. In Excel it's called LEV.

```
=LAMBDA(a,b,[ii],[jj],[arr],
        LET(
            i,IF(ISOMITTED(ii),1,ii),
            j,IF(ISOMITTED(jj),1,jj),
            a_i,MID(a,i,1),
            b_j,MID(b,j,1),
            init_array,MAKEARRAY(
                    LEN(a)+1,
                    LEN(b)+1,
                    LAMBDA(r,c,IFS(r=1,c-1,c=1,r-1,TRUE,0))
                    ),
            cost,N(NOT(a_i=b_j)),
            this_arr,IF(ISOMITTED(arr),init_array,arr),
            option_a,INDEX(this_arr,i+1-1,j+1)+1,
            option_b,INDEX(this_arr,i+1,j+1-1)+1,
            option_c,INDEX(this_arr,i+1-1,j+1-1)+cost,
            new_val,MIN(option_a,option_b,option_c),
            overlay,MAKEARRAY(
                    LEN(a)+1,
                    LEN(b)+1,
                    LAMBDA(r,c,IF(AND(r=i+1,c=j+1),new_val,0))
                    ),
            new_arr,this_arr+overlay,
            new_i,IF(i=LEN(a),IF(j=LEN(b),i+1,1),i+1),
            new_j,IF(i<>LEN(a),j,IF(j=LEN(b),j+1,j+1)),
            is_end,AND(new_i>LEN(a),new_j>LEN(b)),
            IF(is_end,new_val,LEV(a,b,new_i,new_j,new_arr))
            )
)
```

It works fine when comparing two strings. For example, if I pass in

```
=lev("book","back")
```

it returns 2.

However, if c2 contains

```
book look
```

And I put in

```
=lev(textsplit(c2," "),"back")
```

It returns `#N/A`. I want it to return

```
2
3
```

To be honest, I don't know where to start in troubleshooting this function. Can anyone help?

@Ike's answer very helpfully answered the question, but unfortunately my question was a bit ill-stated.

I need to get the lev distance between every word in c2 and d2.

Suppose c2 is

```
red ball
```

And d2 is

```
yellow window
```

The desired output would be the levenstein distance between each word in c2 and d2.

There are 4 possible comparisons: red/yellow, red/bat, ball/yellow, and ball/bat.

Desired output:

```
5
4
5
6
```

Note that I only want comparison between arrays, not within them. I don't want the distance between red and ball, because they're part of the same array.

Comment: BTW, `=BYROW(TEXTSPLIT(C2,," "),LAMBDA(r,LEV(r,"back")))` returns `{#REF!;#REF!}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this formula:

```
=LET(a,C2,b,D2,
aSplit,TEXTSPLIT(a,," "),
DROP(REDUCE("",aSplit,LAMBDA(r,x,VSTACK(r,lev(x,b)))),1))
```

[image]

As @vbasic2008 said, `BYROW` doesn't work.

Passing an array to the Lev-Lambda would need another step of recursion within the Lambda function.

Using `REDUCE` like this keeps the Lev-Lambda untouched.

**** EDIT due to comment ****

```vb
=LET(a,C2,b,E2,
aSplit,TEXTSPLIT(a," "),
bSplit,TEXTSPLIT(b," "),
r, DROP(REDUCE("",bSplit,LAMBDA(r_2,x_2,VSTACK(r_2,
DROP(REDUCE("",aSplit,LAMBDA(r,x,HSTACK(r,lev(x,x_2)))),,1)))),1),
HSTACK(VSTACK("",TRANSPOSE(bSplit)),VSTACK(aSplit,r))
)
```

[image]

Comment: This works, thank you. I should have thought of it before but I need it to accept arrays on *both* 'sides' of the formula. That is, D2 needs to be textsplit as well as c2. I need to get the lev distance between every word in c2 and d2. Is there a way I can adapt your formula to do that?

Comment: I updated the formula - you need another `REDUCE` - and I enhanced the formula so that it shows the values of both sides

Answer (score 0):

If you're committed to using the LAMBDA formula, this solution won't solve that; however, if you're trying to calculation the Levenshtein, then you can use this VBA function, that will appear in your excel as a formula, and you can input the 2 variables to calculate their distance.

This isn't something I wrote, but was able to find online [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243036/levenshtein-distance-in-vba), more specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4243652/11820046)

1. Alt + F11 or add the "Developer" tab to your excel ribbon and open the "Visual Basic" Window
2. In the left section, right-click and insert a new module.
3. Copy and paste the code below into Module1
4. `=LEVENSHTEIN( [Input1], [Input2] )`

```
Option Explicit
Public Function Levenshtein(s1 As String, s2 As String)

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim l1 As Integer
Dim l2 As Integer
Dim d() As Integer
Dim min1 As Integer
Dim min2 As Integer

l1 = Len(s1)
l2 = Len(s2)
ReDim d(l1, l2)
For i = 0 To l1
    d(i, 0) = i
Next
For j = 0 To l2
    d(0, j) = j
Next
For i = 1 To l1
    For j = 1 To l2
        If Mid(s1, i, 1) = Mid(s2, j, 1) Then
            d(i, j) = d(i - 1, j - 1)
        Else
            min1 = d(i - 1, j) + 1
            min2 = d(i, j - 1) + 1
            If min2 < min1 Then
                min1 = min2
            End If
            min2 = d(i - 1, j - 1) + 1
            If min2 < min1 Then
                min1 = min2
            End If
            d(i, j) = min1
        End If
    Next
Next
Levenshtein = d(l1, l2)
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you. I need to share the spreadsheet with non technical users, who will balls it up if they have to enable macros. In general I try to avoid vb as it's on the way out.

Answer (score 0):

Your **LAMBDA** seems work with single strings, not arrays. So when you pass an array to the function, it doesn't know how to handle it and maybe cause to returns `#N/A`. Therefore, try use `SEQUENCE` to generate an array of indices, and then apply your function to each element of the array. Then use `BYROW` to apply your **LAMBDA** to each row of the array:

```
=LAMBDA(a,b,[ii],[jj],[arr],
    LET(
        i,IF(ISOMITTED(ii),1,ii),
        j,IF(ISOMITTED(jj),1,jj),
        a_i,MID(a,i,1),
        b_j,MID(b,j,1),
        init_array,MAKEARRAY(
                LEN(a)+1,
                LEN(b)+1,
                LAMBDA(r,c,IFS(r=1,c-1,c=1,r-1,TRUE,0))
                ),
        cost,N(NOT(a_i=b_j)),
        this_arr,IF(ISOMITTED(arr),init_array,arr),
        option_a,INDEX(this_arr,i+1-1,j+1)+1,
        option_b,INDEX(this_arr,i+1,j+1-1)+1,
        option_c,INDEX(this_arr,i+1-1,j+1-1)+cost,
        new_val,MIN(option_a,option_b,option_c),
        overlay,MAKEARRAY(
                LEN(a)+1,
                LEN(b)+1,
                LAMBDA(r,c,IF(AND(r=i+1,c=j+1),new_val,0))
                ),
        new_arr,this_arr+overlay,
        new_i,IF(i=LEN(a),IF(j=LEN(b),i+1,1),i+1),
        new_j,IF(i<>LEN(a),j,IF(j=LEN(b),j+1,j+1)),
        is_end,AND(new_i>LEN(a),new_j>LEN(b)),
        IF(is_end,new_val,LEV(a,b,new_i,new_j,new_arr))
    )
)

=BYROW(TEXTSPLIT(C2," "),LAMBDA(x,LEV(x,"back")))
```

Comment: Didn't I write in the comments that this doesn't work? Have you tried it?

Comment: How about `=ARRAYFORMULA(LAMBDA(x,LEV(x,"back"))(TEXTSPLIT(C2," ")))`??

Comment: There is no `ARRAYFORMULA` in Excel, it's a *Google Sheets* thing.